# PostSharp - Applying aspect to mscorlib but prohibit modifying calls in my own class

Tags: .net-assembly, postsharp

My aspect:

```
[Serializable]
class DumbLogger : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Log.Print("Entry: ") + args.Method.Name;
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
    }
}
```

This is what i am using to modify the calls in mscorlib AND trying to exclude them from being modified in my class called LOG

```
    [assembly: MY_PROJECT.DumbLogger(
    AttributeTargetTypes = "MY_PROJECT.Log",
    AttributeExclude = true,
    AttributePriority = 1)]


    [assembly: MY_PROJECT.DumbLogger(
    AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib",
    AttributePriority = 2)]
```

But.. This doesnt do the trick because if i look at my LOG class with ILspy decompiler i can see method calls to any class @ mscorlib.dll being modified for example:

```
<>z__Aspects.<System.Object.ToString>b__v(text)
```

The reason i wanna do this is because when i enter the method Log.Print it will generate a stackoverflow exception and will infinitely call itself.

I am already aware of maybe excluding certain namespaces and classes like string from mscorlib but i have my reasons to do it the way i described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostSharp Aspects in general are applied to declarations (assemblies, types, methods, parameters, fields, etc.). When you are applying an `MethodLevelAspect` (base class of `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`) on an external method, PostSharp transforms the call site (`call` instruction in IL), but still thinks of the aspect as being on the declaration itself.

There is currently no way to filter by call site and it would require a different kind of aspect and/or advices. Therefore your `AttributeExclude=true` specifying attribute on the assembly does not have any effect as it says that the aspect should not be applied on `Log` type, which it is not.

The common technique that solves exactly this case is to use a `ThreadStatic` variable to break the recursion cycle as the following code demonstrates:

```
[Serializable]
class DumbLogger : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    [ThreadStatic] private static bool logging;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (logging)
            return;

        try
        {
            logging = true;
            Log.Print("Entry: " + args.Method.Name);
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
        }
        finally
        {
            logging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please also note that `MethodInterception` and `OnMethodBoundary` aspects are the only aspect that work on external assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this works, i received this answer a while ago(not really related to the question) but i thought there was a less "workaround"ish way...

Comment: @JoaoVitor Currently there is no other way. That may change in the future, but we have no set plans for something like `CallSiteLevelAspect` as the number of use cases impossible without it seems quite small.